# Morphia ignores collation

Tags: java, mongodb, collation, morphia

I have a mongo 3.4 server and I need to run case insensitive queries. 
I have created the proper index and I can make case insensitive queries through the mongo console.

```
    db.users.find(  {"name": "alex" }, { "name" : 1 } ).collation( { locale: 'en', strength: 2 } )
```

returns any user that has as name Alex, alex, ALEX etc

I need to do the same from my java program that uses morphia 1.3.1.

```
    Collation col = Collation.builder().locale("en").collationStrength(CollationStrength.SECONDARY).build();
    FindOptions fo = new FindOptions().collation(col);
    q.disableValidation().asList(fo);
```

The program retuns only the users that has as name the pecified parameter.
If i set the name as Alex then I will not get the users with name alex, ALEX etc
Is there something extra that I had to do with morphia to make the collation to work?

Answer (score 0):

I have alternate way to solve your problem.
Use regular expression in query.

> db.users.find({"name":{$regex:/^alex$/i}})

To do this in java code. Write one java function which will construct string like above e.g.

> {"name":{$regex:/^alex$/i}}

And use below code to get DBCursor

```
public DBCursor find(String jsonString) {
    if(StringUtils.trimToNull(jsonString) != null) {
            DBObject dbObject = (DBObject)JSON.parse(jsonString);
            return collection.find(dbObject);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then get list of DBObject from DBCursor and use morphia.fromDBObject function to get your result in required class.

Another way you can go is Create text index on required fields and search with whatever you want. see details here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-operator-case-sensitivity

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the problem with this solutions is that it can not use indexes and my collection has over a million users. With mongo 3.4 and the collation usage you can do the thing that you could before with the regex but you have indexes also.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Can't be done by adding text index on required field ?

Comment: it can but text indexes have other limitations and also they are slower